# Convert dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm to date/time in Excel

Tags: date, excel-formula

I've found tons of post on how to convert `dd/mm` etc but no post on what to do when you have `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm`.

So, anyone knows what to do?

Comment: Have you tried replacing "." with "/", and then following the posts that you've found?  (If using a formula to run the calculation, try `SUBSTITUTE`)

Comment: @Chronocidal - that suggestion should come with a warning about corrupting DMY data on an MDY system where ambiguous days/months may become interchanged. e.g. 07.04.2018 (in dd.mm.yyy) could easily become 04-Jul-2018 during a bulk conversion with an MDY regional date setting.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is probably in a text format, especially if it comes off a web-based report or .CSV file. Use the following steps to convert it to dates:

1. Select the range that you want to convert
2. Then select 'Data' from the ribbon and click on the 'Text to Columns' tool
3. Click the 'Next' button twice (2x)
4. In Step 3 of the Wizard, select the 'Date' button in the Column data format section and make sure the format shown in the dropdown next to the button is the one you want
5. Click on 'Finish'
6. You may end up seeing the data in your range in the time format, but you can now use the regular format tool to change it to the desired date format (ex. MM/DD/YYYY)